# How to keep a socket connection alive in an Android home screen widget

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, appwidgetprovider

I have a widget: `class SmartAppWidget : AppWidgetProvider()` in this class I open a bluetooth socket connection, but it always connects and disconnects, how do I keep the connection alive in home screen widget? any suggestions would be great. Thanks.

It's just a button that send commands over bluetooth when you click it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/smart_app_widget"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/smart_app_widget"
    android:minWidth="60dp"
    android:minHeight="60dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:configure="co.za.chester.smartcontroller.DeviceListActivity"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen"></appwidget-provider>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `AppWidgetProvider` is simply a manifest-registered subclass of `BroadcastReceiver`. By design, it does not stay alive — your `AppWidgetProvider` instance lives for a single call to `onReceive()` (and from there to `onUpdate()` or whatever).

If you want to try to maintain a Bluetooth connection without an activity in the foreground, use a foreground service.

Comment: I want to keep receiving system broadcast Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK to update my widget. How to keep it alive without showing notice icon in status bar? I am entangled between foreground service and background service or something else. Any suggestions? Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70032050/can-i-use-action-time-tick-to-update-android-time-widget

Comment: @Krahmal: "I want to keep receiving system broadcast Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK to update my widget -- Google and device manufacturers would prefer that you do not, because users complain that apps that do this sort of thing drain the battery too much. "How to keep it alive without showing notice icon in status bar?" -- create your own launcher app, where your app widget is not really an `AppWidgetProvider` but rather is a feature of your launcher.

Comment: Thank you. This is an idea I never thought of. I am very new to launcher. Do you mean a custom launcher is active forever so the receiver in it will never be kill?

Comment: @Krahmal: "Do you mean a custom launcher is active forever so the receiver in it will never be kill?" -- no. But, it is guaranteed to be active when it is visible to the user, which is all that matters for what had once been an app widget.

Comment: Thanks. I' ll try this. But I am still confused how other apps do this stably and reliably as widget.

Comment: @Krahmal: I do not know what "do this" is. Few app widgets would use `ACTION_TIME_TICK`, and I do not know what your app widget is trying to do given that action. You might consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question where you explain in detail what your functionality objectives are and ask for solutions.

Comment: The link above is my question. May be I' m not familiar with the rules of the forum, and I have very few answers. I want to update widget text every 60s(not TextClock). I' ve tried alarm(send my broadcast), foreground service(start. by my or system broadcast), but still not find the best way

Comment: @Krahmal: "I want to update widget text every 60s(not TextClock)" -- that is impractical, and you will find roughly zero third-party app widgets that "do this stably and reliably".

Comment: I forgot what the app was called before but now I find it: [KWGT](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kustom.widget&hl=en&gl=us) and seems like using [background?foreground service](https://help.kustom.rocks/i1726-persistent-notification) to update every minute. Its service lives longer than mine.